# In vbs/hta how do I tell if I reach the end of a word document?

Tags: vba, vbscript, hta

I am currently creating a large script to automate a Microsoft word document to pull out tables and put them into a new document. But I need to know when I reach the end of the document so I can move on to the next document.

```
Set objWord         = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objNewDoc       = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objNewSelection = objWord.Selection
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open( C:/Users/blahdoc.doc )
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
```

This isn't the script but its how I defined and opened the documents for reading. I will happily insert more details if and when there needed.

I did look around for similar questions but didn't find any that apply. If you do sorry ahead of time ;)

Comment: From Snhp9: "I need all of the text/images/everything. But only sorting through tables with a certain tag in the first column."
Please change your problem statement to explain what exactly you want to pull out. It currently only says tables, and includes nothing about sorting tables. Also, you may want to include what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to worry about "reaching the end of the document."  Thankfully, the tables are stored in a `Tables` collection which is a property of a `Word.Document`. You can iterate through all the tables like so:

```
For Each oTable In objNewDoc.Tables
    If Left(oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, Len(oTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text) - 2) = "Some string" Then
        MsgBox "Found one!"
    End If
Next
```

One issue I ran into when putting this together is that all Cells' Text have an End-of-Cell Marker composed of two characters: a Carriage Return (ascii 13) followed by a BELL (ascii 7).  I used `Left` to strip those off so I could compare the text against a string value, which is what I understand you are trying to do.